# Put all package options into one command

Tags: macros, packages, revision-control

The title might not be perfect, but what I want to achieve is:

Inside my own package `mypackage.sty`, I would like to have a command, say `\allpackageoptions`, which should have stored the entire package option string. Like this:

### Example Code

Document (`mydocument.tex`):

```
\usepackage[Lorem Ipsum Dolor]{mypackage}
```

Package (`mypackage.sty`):

```
[...]
\allpackageoptions % shoud output 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor'
[...]
```

### Background

What I would like to achieve with this is to write a small package that simplifies the use of svn keywords. (I know there are some packages out there, but I want something really tiny and simple).
SVN can automatically insert a string containing version information whereever I want whenever I commit the file. Look at this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\svn $Id: #1 #2 #3-#4-#5 #6${%
    This file is revision r#2.
}

\begin{document}

\svn $Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $
    %This string inside $$ is automatically updated by SVN

\end{document}
```

The output of this example code is obviously `This file is revision r259`. My package would provide this interface:

```
\usepackage[$Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $]{mysvn}
```

and should provide a command `\svnrevision` which outputs `259`.

Comment: Which keyval package do you use? However options are separated by commas. In your case there is no comma and everything can be save in a single token.

Comment: I usually use `kvoptions` or the default `DeclareOption`-solution – but I am open for everything.

Comment: `kvoptions` saves all options inside the command `\KVO@classoptionslist`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem with the option approach is that LaTeX removes the spaces inside the option.

```
\usepackage[$Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $]{mysvn}
```

The package will see:

```
$Id:somefile.tex2592013-04-2013:22:00Zralfix$
```

That will make the parsing much more cumbersome. Also curly braces will not help:

```
\usepackage[{$Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $}]{mysvn}
```

The braces are already stripped by `\usepackage`, when it reads its optional argument. This can be prevented by an additional empty option:

```
\usepackage[,{$Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $}]{mysvn}
```

Or using a key value interface:

```
\usepackage[id={$Id: somefile.tex 259 2013-04-20 13:22:00Z ralfix $}]{mysvn}
```

Packages `kvoptions-patch` and `xkvltxp` redefine LateX internals for a better support of spaces and macros inside LaTeX options. But they have to be loaded *before* such options are used.

Package `kvoptions` can be used to catch the local options, e.g.:

```
% mysvn.sty
% Syntax: \usepackage[,{$Id: ...}]{mysvn}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysvn}[2013/04/20 SVN version number]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}[2009/07/17]

\DeclareDefaultOption{%
  % dummy actions
  % * print option value on screen
  \typeout{[\CurrentOption]}%
  % * remember option value in \mysvnid
  \let\mysvnid\CurrentOption
}
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*
\endinput
```

Example with a key-value option:

```
% mysvn.sty
% Syntax: \usepackage[id={$Id: ...}]{mysvn}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysvn}[2013/04/20 SVN version number]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}[2009/07/17]

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=mysvn,
  prefix=mysvn@,
}
% Store value of option `id' in `\mysvn@id`:
\DeclareStringOption{id}
\DeclareLocalOptions{id}% global `id' options are ignored
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\endinput
```

Much easier would be a macro interface without options at all:

```
\usepackage{mysvn}
\mysvn{$Id: ...}
```

I would left the parsing of the SVN identification string to a specialized package:

- Parsing of a full Id string.
- Parsing of a compressed Id String, when subversion has not yet written the full Id string.
- Error handling, if the string is not an Id string.

Comment: Until now, I do not need a full-blown package with extended parsing abilities – my simple approach is enough. Thank you for the idea with the macro interface, regarding the "problems" with space-removal this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 8):

The options passed to the package `foo.sty` are saved in the macro `\opt@foo.sty` so you can simply do

```
\newcommand\alloptionslist[1]{\@nameuse{opt@#1.sty}}
```

The output is just the contents of the optional argument to `\usepackage`, without any interpretation. But it's easy to manage a comma separated list.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question about a command which holds the entire options... however concerning my special case I need the spaces to be kept.

Comment: At what point does `\opt@foo.sty` become available? I've tried using `\@nameuse{opt@foo.sty}` in the file, `foo.sty` and get the error "Undefined control sequence. `\opt@foo`".