# Passing formatting options in pgfkeys using pgfopts

Tags: macros, package-writing, pgfkeys, package-options, pgfopts

I am trying to design packages and handle package options using `pgfkeys` through the `pgfopts` package. However when an option include a formatting command, the whole thing fail and I don't get the expected result.

Here is my test package: `pgfoptstest.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{pgfoptstest}[2020/01/01 pgfopts test]
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfoptstest/.cd,
    format/.store in = \format,
    format = \textit,
    example/.store in = \example,
    example = {This is an \format{example}.},
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/pgfoptstest}
\newcommand{\makeexample}{\example}
\newcommand{\maketest}[1]{\format{#1}}
```

And here is my test file: `pgfoptstest.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfoptstest}                                           % OK
%\usepackage[format =]{pgfoptstest}                                % OK
%\usepackage[example = {Another example.}]{pgfoptstest}            % NO SPACES
%\usepackage[example = {{Another example.}}]{pgfoptstest}          % OK
%\usepackage[example = {{Another \textbf{example}.}}]{pgfoptstest} % ERROR
%\usepackage[format = \textbf]{pgfoptstest}                        % ERROR
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makeexample{}\\
\maketest{This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

How to fix it (ideally on the package side so the user do not have to write their options in a tricky way) so that the lines marked as `ERROR` work properly?

And as a bonus, is there a way to make the line marked as `NO SPACES` work properly so that the user does not have to type two pairs of braces?

Comment: I think that instead of `\textit` and `\textbf` you want to use the commands `\itshape` and `\bfseries` here. Then you can copy more or less the `font` key of Ti*k*Z/pgf.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat But I would like to be able to handle options themselves containing formatted text (with macros I don't know in advance). Things like: `\usepackage[example = {{Another \textbf{example}.}}]{pgfoptstest}`

Comment: The pgfopts documentation says: "An important point to notice is that the key names do not contain a space.This is because the LaTeX kernel removes spaces from options before they are passed to the class or package. Spaces can occur in the path to the key, but not in the key name itself. This restriction only applies to keys used as options". That's possibly why your spaces do not appear unless you enclose your text in brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, I'm afraid I've got some sad news.
This is not caused by `pgfkeys` or `pgfopts`, but by the way LaTeX itself handles package options. It strips spaces and performs a couple of expansions before passing the options on. There is literally nothing that can be done about it at the package level because it's already too late by the time the package sees them.

:(

Unfortunately, replacing `\textbf` by `\protect\textbf` and `\noexpand\textbf` doesn't help either.
What does work is replacing `\textbf` by `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\textbf`, but that doesn't make for a particularly appealing syntax…

I would expect this question to come up periodically, but a quick search only turned up [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/489564/156366), which is about the same problem with `kvoptions`. (Maybe I'm not using the right search terms.)
The one bit of good news there is that David says that “there may be plans to change this [normalisation during option handling]” in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489570/156366).

---

#### Suggestion #1

Before this edit, I sort of jokingly mentioned that writing a package to patch how LaTeX handles options was also an option.
I did a little searching and it turns out that, unsurprisingly, someone already did just that.
If you load the `kvoptions-patch` package (which is described in the [`kvoptions` documentation](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/kvoptions/kvoptions.pdf)) before loading your own package, options with spaces or macros that you don't want expanded will work!

Here's your MWE with one line added to it:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{pgfoptstest.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{pgfoptstest}[2020/01/01 pgfopts test]
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfoptstest/.cd,
    format/.store in = \format,
    format = \textit,
    example/.store in = \example,
    example = {This is an \format{example}.},
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/pgfoptstest}
\newcommand{\makeexample}{\example}
\newcommand{\maketest}[1]{\format{#1}}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvoptions-patch} %% <- added
\usepackage[example = Another \textbf{example}.]{pgfoptstest} % OK now
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makeexample{}\\
\maketest{This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

#### Suggestion #2

Or you could create a setup function that the user has to call to set up your package. It's not as nice as an option, but probably better than asking your users to `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand` their unexpandable macros.

```
\begin{filecontents}{pgfoptstest2.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{pgfoptstest2}[2020/01/01 pgfopts test]

\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfoptstest/.cd,
    format/.store in = \format,
    format = \textit,
    example/.store in = \example,
    example = {This is an \format{example}.},
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/pgfoptstest} %% <- optional (badum, tss)

\newcommand*\pgfoptstestsetup[1]{\pgfqkeys{/pgfoptstest}{#1}}

\newcommand{\makeexample}{\example}
\newcommand{\maketest}[1]{\format{#1}}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfoptstest2}
\pgfoptstestsetup{
  format=\underline,
  example = \textbf{Another example.}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makeexample{}\\
\maketest{This is a test.}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

### Addendum (experiment)

Here's a little experiment to demonstrate that there's no way to avoid this at the package level.

```
\begin{filecontents}{stop.sty}
\stop %% <- abort immediately
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{stop} %% <- successfully produces nothing
\usepackage[example = {{Another \textbf{example}.}}]{stop} %% <- errors
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

- If no options are passed to `stop.sty`, everything is fine: TeX stops in the middle of loading the package and produces no output (and no errors).
- If (for instance) `example=\textbf{example}` is passed as an option, all hell breaks loose.
  The error messages are the same as in your MWE.

Comment: Thanks for your very complete and precise answer, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck with your packages.